# python imaplib gmail fetching multiple results from list

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain email ids and then fetch all of them. How do I do this? Thanks!

The following is my code:

```
import imaplib
import re

user = 'user'
pwd = 'password'
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
imap_server.login(user, pwd)
imap_server.select('Inbox')
typ, response = imap_server.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Hello")')
response = str(response[0])
response_re = re.compile('\d+')
response_pat = re.findall(response_re, response)

for i in response_pat:
    results, datas = imap_server.fetch(i, "(RFC822)")
```

for i in datas:

```
print i
```

## this still on print one value of datas, when I have iterated through a list of multiple #values.

Comment: please stop using bold and large print text to tell us what you want. If you are asking a question, ask politely.

Comment: if you want to iterate through the data, you have to store it for each fetch you make. create a list: `datas = []`, then append the data to the list. `datas.append(data)`

Comment: @JasonYeo He is not using bold, he is just not formatting properly... (i.e. it's a hash-comment, what seems like bold text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake with the command. It should be `RFC822` instead of `RCF822`. Simply just change one line of your code. Change this line from

```
results, datas = imap_server.fetch(i, "(RCF822)")
```

to

```
results, datas = imap_server.fetch(i, "(RFC822)")
```

And also, don't use regex when you can simply use string libraries. Instead of using regex, simply do this in your loop:

```
for i in response[0].split():
    results, datas = m.fetch(i, "(RFC822)")
```